# Mirosoft office on Docker container

Tags: docker, ms-office, jira

I have a docker container running Jira software and i have a Jira plugin which i install in Jira.
The plugin needs access to wordconv.exe from MS Office to convert .doc files into .docx

```
private static String officePath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/root/Office16/wordconv.exe";

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
        officePath,
        "-oice",
        "-nme",
        inputPath,
        outputPath
});
```

I tested this code on Windows and it works with no problem, but when i install the artifact in Jira running on the container it does not work anymore.
How should i do to have the plugin have access to MS Office.
can i just install MS Office on the host server an have the container access it's resources or do i need to install MS Office on the container or do i need to create a container running MS Office ?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the idea of docker images is to be portable and you would want anyone using the docker images (with JIRA) to be able to do the conversion from doc to docx then yes, the docker image should include MS Office.